# Extracting a specific table from a HTML page

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to extract the following table from a HTML table.

I have a HTML txt file. Found at:

saved html file: https://files.fm/u/fzw4qkmvr
raw text file: https://files.fm/u/z4y8s9s52

(the both files are the same, one is saved as a HTML page and the other as a .txt)

I am trying to extract the following table:

[image]

Running the following:

```
myHTML = read_html("output_table.html")

myHTML %>%
  html_table()
```

Gives me a list of 72 - but I would like only the specific table of information.

Comment: You can use indexing if you know which table it is: `html_table(read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_national_capitals"))[[1]]` If you know HTML characteristics specific to that table (e.g., name, class), you can filter for it that way. If all else fails, you could use `lapply`, something like this: `res <- lapply(myh2, function(j) {
  whichOne <- grepl("City", names(j));
  if(any(whichOne)) j;
  }) %>% Filter(function(k) length(k) > 0, .) %>% 
  as.data.frame()`  Just change "City" for a column name specific to the table you're looking for (where `myh2` is list of tables).